# MySQL query to get Records in Result set

Tags: java, mysql, resultset

I have table T1.

```
id | name | surname
1    AA      XX
2    BB      YY
3    CC      ZZ
```

I want such query which will return

all data of rows, where id=1 & id =2

Comment: Select * From Google where questionposted IN ('What have you tried ? ')

Comment: That's very basic SQL. You should find a beginner's tutorial and go through at least the basics, and try something, before coming here.

Comment: Also, it shouldn't be possible for an id to be equal to 1 AND to 2.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I want to get the both rows.

Comment: +1 @m hasan .. select * from T1 where id in ('1','2');  :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE id IN (1,2);
```